# Schema Validation of Rest API Serenity BDD

Tags: rest-assured, json-schema-validator, serenity-bdd

I am facing a strange issue that I extract a schema of api response and added json file in my serenity project. While validating schema, what ever the schema provided the test was passing, moreover if I changed any type of key like I change the data-type of any key value correct schema( like changed the name data-type from string to integer) then test failed.

Scenario:

My API response:

```
{
   "name":"Alex",
   "age" : 20,
   "city":"New York"

}
```

My Schema for this API: **Test Passed** which is ok

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "city": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "age",
    "city"
  ]
}
```

If I changed the schema from correct to wrong that is remove any key value pair the test even passed which is not correct

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
  
    "city": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "city"
  ]
}
```

Moreover if I write only " `{ }` " in the Schema file the test passed

The method I am using for validation is **matchesJsonSchemaInClassPath**

Answer (score 0):

The schema validation only checks the data-types that are coming for values in JSON are correct by matching with schema. For the data validation there is another method in Serenity BDD that is `VerifyResponseData.ofTheresponse(jsonobj)`

This works for me